# Finding max occurring number in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find the most occurring Number in an integer array but it fails when there there are two or more max repeating Numbers.

Here is my Code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,n,*a,temp,count,maxCount=0,value;
    cout<<"Enter Size of Array\n";
    cin>>n;
    a = new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                count++;
                temp=a[i];
            }
        }
        if(count>maxCount)
        {
            maxCount=count;
            value=temp;

        }
    }
    cout<<value<<" repeating max time i.e. "<<maxCount;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You put `i++` in the loop on `j`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: j++ instead of i++ for second loop..

Comment: BTW, memleak... Use `std::vector`.

Comment: What does “it fails” mean? It doesn't compile? It gets a runtime error? What's the error? It doesn't do what you think it should? What does it do? What do you think it should do?

Comment: Don't write it yourself. Try [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: Please do not edit the question to remove/fix the problem you are asking about, especially if there are answers which will become invalid/obsolete then.

Answer (score 2):

The loop on `j` should increment `j`, not `i`.

This is the one of the risks of using copy-n-paste.

Comment: Ohh yes! But it was not Copied! Thanks Anyways Sir!